# url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

i developped a flutter app and i install the package named **url_launcher** to open the link from the android studio then when i run the app on my physical device ,it give me a error in the below , first i think it from the internet then it faild to run even in the good internet

> Execution failed for task
> ':url_launcher_android:extractDebugAnnotations'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url_launcher_android:detachedConfiguration1'.
> > Could not find intellij-core-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.3.0).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.3.0/intellij-core-30.3.0.jar
> > Could not find kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.3.0).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.0/kotlin-compiler-30.3.0.jar